# Closed surfaces of prescribed mean curvature

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, mg.metric-geometry, curvature, hypersurfaces

Let $D\subset\mathbb R^n$ be a smoothly bounded open domain and $0\in D$. For any $x\in\partial D$ there holds
\begin{eqnarray*}
2 \,a'(\vert x\vert)\,(x\cdot\nu(x))+(n-1)\,a(\vert x\vert) \, H(x) = \text{const.}
\end{eqnarray*}
Here $a:(0,\infty)\to (0,\infty)$ is a positive smooth function, $a'$ denotes its derivative, $\nu(x)$ is the outer unit normal vector in $x\in\partial D$ and $(n-1)H(x)$ denotes the mean curvature in $x\in\partial D$. Does this imply that $D$ is a ball?

Answer (score 3):

If you let $\partial D$ be a hypersurface of revolution whose generatrix $\gamma: I \to [0,\infty) \times \mathbb{R}$ is such that $|\gamma|$ is monotonic, you then have $H(x)$ and $x\cdot \nu(x)$ can both be written as functions of $|x|$ only. One can further arrange that $x\cdot \nu(x) > \epsilon > 0$ for all positions.

Let $G(|x|) = H(x) / x \cdot \nu(x)$.

If you choose $a(s)$ to be any solution of

$$ (\ln a(s))' = \frac{1-n}{2} G(s) $$

your desired equation is satisfied with constant 0.

Comment: Many thanks! Would the answer be also affirmative, if the monotonicity assumption on $\vert\gamma\vert$ fails?

Comment: @guest61: I don't understand your comment. My answer provides infinitely many  **counterexamples** to your claim.

Comment: I don't see why a surface of revolution has a mean curvature that only depends on the modulus of the position vector? The same question for $x\cdot\nu(x)$?

Comment: the **monotonicity** assumption forces there to be exactly one circle for each value of $|x|$, and the mean curvature is obviously constant on that one circle by rotational symmetry.